# How to compare columns in a where clause in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have 1 table formatted like this:

```
Client    Code   Document
AAA       1      001
AAA       3      002
003-00    2      003B
CCC       1      004
001-01    2      001A
```

I am trying to filter this data down to only where Client = 'AAA', Code = 1 or Code =2, and any other rows where the first three characters of the Document match a document of a row where Client = AAA.  In this example I would want my query to return this:

```
Client    Code   Document
AAA       1      001
001-01    2      001A
```

I tried doing it this way and its returning the wrong number of rows, missing information, and duplicating records; so, I am at a loss

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.Client, B.Client) Client,
       COALESCE(A.Code, B.Code) Code, 
       COALESCE(A.Document, B. Document) Document
FROM 
       (SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Client = 'AAA' AND Code = 1) A
LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Code = 2) B ON A.Document = LEFT(B.Document,3)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description of requirements, the following gets your desired results

```
select * 
from t
where (client='AAA' and code in (1,2)) 
or Left(client,3) in (select document from t where client='AAA')
```

See [DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b3854e02c6fce8fcdb74c0583776c44b)

Answer (score 0):

The following gets the desired results but the data set you provided is too small to determine if this will work for other scenarios.

```
SELECT B.*
FROM MyTable A
INNER JOIN MyTable B ON (A.Document = LEFT(B.Document,3)) 
WHERE A.Client = 'AAA' and (A.Code = 1 OR A.Code = 2)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c1523c/14)